# reduce() to return array of strings from multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, reduce

I'm trying to use .reduce() to return a single array of strings from multiple Objects. Can anyone give me an idea of how to do that? I've tried to use Object.fromEntries() too but without much luck so far.

This is my code:

```
    let searchList = searchOptions.map((optionList) => Object.entries(optionList).map(
        ([category, categoryValue]) => {return category === 'illness' ? categoryValue.map(illnessList => illnessList.list.map(illness => illness)):
        category === 'products' ? categoryValue.map(product => product.name) : categoryValue.map(doctor => doctor.name.firstName + " " + doctor.name.lastName)
    }))

    console.log('List', searchList)
```

Input:
[image]
This is what I am returning so far.

```
[
  [
    [
      [
        "Cold",
        "Fever",
        "Hair loss"
      ],
      [
        "Arthrities",
        "Anemia",
        "Sleep problems"
      ],
      [
        "Cancer",
        "Lung disease",
        "Covid"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "Aswagandha powder",
      "Vitamin C suplement"
    ],
    [
      "Aldo Ova",
      "Wendy Sanchez",
      "Alejandra Lopez"
    ]
  ]
]
```

What I need is to return an array that contains all the strings from the Objects:

```
[ "Cold", "Fever", "Hair loss", "Arthrities", "Anemia", "Sleep problems", "Cancer", "Lung disease", "Covid", "Aswagandha powder", "Vitamin C supplement", "Aldo Ova", "Wendy Sanchez","Alejandra Lopez"
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: It would help to post a sample of the input and expected output.

Comment: Please show data as text, not as pictures of text. You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(searchList, null, 2))` to get a nice looking representation of the data suitable for pasting.

Comment: @pilchard, I updated the question. Hope is it clearer now

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

After testing and searching a lot, I figured out how to apply reduce() in this double nested Object Array. Here's my final code:

```
    let searchList = searchOptions.map(optionList => Object.entries(optionList).map(([category, categoryValue]) => {
        return (category === 'illness' ? categoryValue.map(illnessList => illnessList.list.map(listArray => listArray)) :
            category === 'products' ? [categoryValue.map(product => product.name)] :
                [categoryValue.map(doctor => `${doctor.name.firstName} ${doctor.name.lastName}`)])
            .reduce((prev, current) => [...prev, ...current], [])
    }).reduce((prev, current) => [...prev, ...current], []))

    searchList = searchList.reduce((prev, current) => [...prev, ...current], [])

    console.log('List', searchList)
```

Result:

```
[
  "Cold",
  "Fever",
  "Hair loss",
  "Arthrities",
  "Anemia",
  "Sleep problems",
  "Cancer",
  "Lung disease",
  "Covid",
  "Aswagandha powder",
  "Vitamin C suplement",
  "Aldo Ova",
  "Wendy Sanchez",
  "Alejandra Lopez"
]
```